# How to set value using jQuery in PHP foreach loop()?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code with PHP foreach:

```
<?php foreach($noOfAdult as $key => $valu) { ?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Start Time</label>
         <input type="text" name="startTime" class="form-control addTime start_time" placeholder="Start Time">
         <input type="hidden" class="set_timestart set_start_time" name="timestart[]" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>End Time</label>
         <input type="text" name="endTime" class="form-control addTime end_time" placeholder="End Time">
         <input type="hidden" class="set_timeend set_end_time" name="timeend[]" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

This visible input field is basically showing a time when I click on it. Now I want when I click on `.start_time` field then it's value will set to `.set_start_time` hidden field.

**Note:** Both visible and hidden input field is in the PHP foreach LOOP.

I am using jQuery `each()` method but no luck :(

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('.start_time').each(function(v, l) {
   $(this).find('.set_start_time').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, It's working now. I am using this jQuery code:

```
$('.start_time').each(function(v, l) {
   $(this).blur(function() {
      $(this).next('.set_start_time').val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Comment: You don't need `.each` to do this (unless I'm missing something).